# What's an efficient way to store a time-series?

Tags: compression, time-series

I've a pretty large amount of data in a horrible format: 16.4GiB of zip files containing `csv` files.
Each `csv` contains lines like

```
TYPE,2014-07-02 04:04:23.806,0.94598,0.94607
```

Basically:

- A `TYPE` (there are 14 different types and they could ideally grow in the future)
- A `timestamp` (in ms)
- 2 float numbers (max 5 decimal places) which have usually a little spread
- All the float numbers of the same `TYPE` have usually very similar values when they're close in time
- The delta between timestamps is under 1s
- The data spans for 5 years

In total I've 3'091'472'167 rows, so we're talking billions. 
The main operations will be looping over part or all the data set (in order to run algorithms on the data) and one insertion of ~20 millions of records once per month (but inserting data is not something I'm interested in optimizing for).

The ideal solution would have been storing them in a database so that I could query them easily, but some rough calculations showed me that I would need [46GiB](https://gist.github.com/framp/b5e9d7f7943824fd2d61) with Postgres (which MAYBE could be brought down to 18GiB with some ugly tricks).

I've done some [experiments](https://gist.github.com/framp/9103a7f1c87b0e87a4d1) with the data I have and I found out that:
    Generating gzipped files containing `TIMESTAMP,FLOAT1,FLOAT2` would get me to ~14GiB
    Removing entirely the timestamps would get me down to ~5GiB

A good way to save space could be storing the timestamp in an efficient way.
I was thinking of creating a tree structure where every node contains one digit of the timestamp and where the leafs contain the final digit and the two floats.

I've tried looking into solutions like druid.io but it looks like they're trying to optimize for other things my use case doesn't need.

Is there some tool I'm missing which does exactly what I want?
If not, what's an efficient way to store time series data?

Thank you

Comment: There's simply not enough information here to say.  Assuming each row is independent of the others, you can probably get each row down to 17 bytes (1 + 8 + 4 + 4).  To reduce it any further, you'd need to do some non-trivial analysis on the redundancy *between* rows.  And from what it sounds like, Gzip is already doing a decent job of that (in its own way).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes it's true, gzip is doing a fine job but probably there is some work I can do on the timestamps to save some space.
I was just wondering what the cool kids do to compress timestamps (if they bother to do it, as I've not been successful in finding anything).

Comment: There's nothing you can to do to "compress" them unless you can make assumptions about the range of values they take.  For example, a 32-bit timestamp will give you ~50 days of range, a 64-bit timestamp will give you 600 million years (!).  But even if you managed to compress them to 0 bits, you're still at 9 bytes per row, which which is still worse than Gzip is managing.

Comment: Not if I compress the 2 floats with gzip. I've done some tests on several archives and removing the timestamps should bring the data from 16.4GiB to ~5GiB.

Comment: Ok, that's roughly 12GB improvement, or 4 bytes per row.  So you'd need to get your timestamps down to, say, 2 bytes on average.  Again, without knowing more about the characteristics of your data, it's basically impossible to give any concrete advice here.  For example, what's the maximum delta between successive timestamps?  If it's less than 65 seconds, for example, then this could work.

Comment: Thanks anyway, really appreciated! What do you think about the idea of serializing a tree structure representing the timestamp with the leafs containing the actual data? Something like: https://gist.github.com/framp/ff890d00c2127decefad
The delta between timestamp is roughly 1 second anyway

Comment: you'd need to think very hard about how that would work in practice.  For example, presumably you're not storing all that whitespace, the `-` and `:`.  But then how *would* you store this so that it could be unambiguously parsed, at an average cost of two bytes per line?

Comment: Re: edit.  If the delta is *always* < 1s, then this is trivial.  Just store the difference between timestamps, which can then be represented by a 16-bit number.

Comment: It's not really always 1s because we don't record data during certain days but it's something we can account for. Interesting tradeoff, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would:

1. Break up the data into several thousand segments, grouped by time.  I don't know the spread of times, but perhaps a file for each hour.
2. Store them in subdirectories by timestamp.  E.g. 2014/07/02/04.
3. Put the *starting* time stamp in the file name.  E.g. `2014-07-02 04:04:23.806.gz`.
4. For all lines, store the type as an index in the first byte.  This permits expansion to 256 types.  If that's not enough, make it two bytes.
5. For all lines the time stamp is a two-byte integer, and the floats are signed n-byte integers, sufficient to hold the values times 10<sup>5</sup>.  I am assuming that these float values are limited in range.  Four bytes for each may be enough.
6. For the first line, the time stamp is zero, representing the difference from the time of that line and the file name.
7. For the first line, the float values are the actual values.
8. For all subsequent lines, the time and float values are the difference from the previous line.  Note that they can be negative.
9. Interleave the most-significant bytes of the values to maximize the runs of zeros for small deltas.
10. Compress each file with [zlib](http://zlib.net/).  In addition to the default mode, try the `Z_FILTERED` and `Z_HUFFMAN` modes to see if the compression is better or worse.

Comment: That's a good idea - but wouldn't the directory and files be a waste of space due to the minimum block size (fs dependant - let's say 4kb)?
I was thinking of replicating such structure serializing a tree inside different files.

Comment: That overhead will be insignificant compared to the file sizes, and will speed up access.

Comment: And it's certainly much easier than inventing another file format.
I think I'm going with this solution (with some minor edits).
Thank you!

Comment: I solved a similar situation slightly differently.  Like @MarkAdler's solution I exported Postgres to CSVs with the date info encoded in the filename - however I also sorted each column to maximize repetitions. After the CSV was generated, I applied a python script that used the `zip` function to pivot the data from a rowstore to column store (more repetition!), then compressed it with `lzma`. The mix of sorting, cstore and lzma resulted in my files being roughly 40% the size of unoptimized zlib CSVs. My total compression was 2.5% the size of raw postgres CSVs with the timestamp as a column.

Comment: This is definitely doable, but QUESTION: is this still the way to go in 2023???

Answer (score 6):

On the PostgreSQL side, you could also use an open source columnar store. This gets you compression, columnar layout, and skip indexes for free. Storage and disk I/O related benefits are:

1. Since column values are stored sequentially, you get better compression ratios
2. The database only reads the columns you are querying, and skips the rest
3. cstore_fdw builds lightweight skip indexes. For time-series data, these indexes automatically filter unrelated data.

For more info: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7523950

If you further need to scale out your queries to multiple CPU cores/machines, you could then use a scalable PostgreSQL: http://www.citusdata.com/downloads

Apart from compression and an efficient data layout, you get PostgreSQL's type checking, data manipulation functionality, and all its querying capabilities for free.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely use a database. PostgreSQL timestamp fields are 8 bytes each. If you use `smallint` for `TYPE` and `real` for your data values (6 decimal place precision), that's 18 bytes per row or over 55GB for your current dataset. Without indexes or nasty hacks.

There appears to be too much focus on storage space. Gigabytes are not expensive. The time you spend trying to get your data out of storage is likely to be more expensive. The timestamp field is very useful for this, because it provides very fine-grained indexing and will allow the database to retrieve the records you want quickly.

Put your data into a database, make the table's primary key a combo of `TYPE` and `TIMESTAMP` and invest in an SSD to hold the data.

Comment: Storage may or may not be expensive, but disk access might be the bottleneck under consideration here.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Michael! I totally understand your point but storage is still important to us and that's what we're trying to optimize for as of now.